# Проверка данных jQuery

Tags: jquery

Такой вот вопросик, как на jQuery проверять какую либо функцию не по клику, а каждые 10секунд, например, у меня есть форма проверки логина в регистрации:

```
$('#reg_login').keyup(function(){
  $('.errorMess').removeClass().empty();
  $('#reg_login').css({'border':'#7ea4cc 1px solid'});
  if(($('#reg_login').val().length)<4 || ($('#reg_login').val().length)>16){
    $('#reg_login').after('<div class=\'errorMess\'>Логин не должен быть меньше 4 и больше 16 символов!</div>');
  } 
  else{
    $.post('ajax/check_login.php', {login:$('#reg_login').val()},function(data){
      if(data == 'yes'){
        $('#reg_login').css({'border':'green 2px solid'});
      }
      else{
        $('#reg_login').after('<div class=\'errorMess\'>Логин уже занят другим пользователем!</div>');  
      }
   });
  }
});
```

Скрипт выполняется каждый раз при нажатии клавиши, а как сделать, чтоб скрипт проверялся каждую секунду? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[setInterval()](http://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval#setinterval)

Comment: Спасибо, работает)

Answer (score 1):

[setInterval](http://kobru.ru/view_post4.php?id=41)